# Javascript, got error "unexpected identifier" when use require instead of import

Tags: javascript

I'm using IAP-receipt-validator in firebase project from 
https://github.com/sibelius/iap-receipt-validator/blob/master/README.md

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
var iapReceiptValidator = require('iap-receipt-validator');
const password = 'xxxx'; // Shared Secret from iTunes connect
const production = false; // use sandbox or production url for validation
var validateReceipt = iapReceiptValidator(password, production);

exports.validate = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  try {
    const validationData = await validateReceipt(request.body.receiptData);
    response.send(JSON.stringify(validationData));
  } catch(err) {
      console.log(err.valid, err.error, err.message)
  }
 });
```

There is an error "Unexpected identifier" while deploying.

By the way, I've change the line

```
import iapReceiptValidator from 'iap-receipt-validator';
```

To

```
var iapReceiptValidator = require('iap-receipt-validator');
```

Please help.

Comment: I don't see `await` anywhere in the code excerpt. Maybe more importantly, I don't see a keyword to assign the module (`const iapReceiptValidator = ...` or `var iapReceiptValidator = ...`).

Comment: Please follow the link on git hub. I’m on mobile and not ready to post long code right now. Thank!

Comment: Try `var iapReceiptValidator = require('iap-receipt-validator');`, or replace var with const.

Comment: Could you please share the error message?

Answer (score 0):

Use following

```
var iapReceiptValidator = require('iap-receipt-validator').default;
```

**Edited:**

The error is because you have use `await` in your code. If you want to use await then your parent function should be annotated with `async`. Like below:

```
exports.validate = functions.https.onRequest(async (request, response) => {
  try {
    const validationData = await validateReceipt(request.body.receiptData);
    response.send(JSON.stringify(validationData));
  } catch(err) {
      console.log(err.valid, err.error, err.message)
  }
});
```

Please check Node.js version your are using should support async/await. Otherwise you have to fallback to promises.

Comment: where are you deploying your code? Are you using Node.js or native browser JavaScript.

Comment: Thank for active answer, Vipin. My mac is running out of battery, will try your solution tonight!

Comment: Please upvote and accept the answer if you are satisfied with it. :)